# How does Parse Query.each count towards execution limits

Tags: parse-platform

I am wondering how the each command on a Parse Query counts towards the request execution limits. I am building an app that will need to perform a function on many objects (could be more than 1000) in a parse class.

For example (in JavaScript),

```
var query = new Parse.Query(Parse.User);
query.equalTo('anObjectIWant',true); //there could be more than 1000 objects I want
query.each(function(object){
  doSomething(object); //doSomething does NOT involve another Parse request
});
```

So, will the above code count as 1 request towards my Parse application execution limit (you get 30/second free), or will each object (each recurrence of calling "each") use one request (so 1000 objects would be 1000 requests)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would count as  1 or 2 depending on :
If it is run from cloudcode function =2,when 1 is for cloudcode call + 1 for query. Since queries get their results all at once it is single call.

If this should be place within "beforeSave" functions or similar then only query would be counted, 1 API call.

So you should be pretty fine as long as you don't trigger another parse API for each result.

Comment: Thank you! I am calling a Parse.Push for each. If I read correctly from other questions, I don't think a push uses a query, right?

Answer (score 4):

I have evaluated the resource usage by observing the number of API requests made by `query.each()` for different result set sizes. The bottom line is that (at the moment of writing) this function is using the default query result count limit of 100. Thus if your query matches up to 100 results it will make 1 API request, 2 API requests for 101-200 and so forth.

This behavior can not be changed by manually increasing the limit to the maximum using `query.limit(1000)`. If you do this you will get an error when you call `query.each()` afterwards (this is also mentioned in the documentation).

Therefore it has to be considered to manually implement this functionality (e.g., by recursive `query.find()`) which allows you to set the query limit to 1000 and thus, in the best case, only consumes one-tenth of the API requests `query.each()` would consume.

Answer (score 0):

I would not be surprised if the .each method would query the server each iteration. 
You can actually check this using their "control panel", just look at the amount of requests beeing made.

We left Parse after doing some prototyping, one of the reasons was that while using proper and sugested code from the parse website, I managed to create 6500 requests a day beeing the only one using the app.
Using our own API, we are down to not more than 100.

Comment: Well with new pricing model only how much requests per seconds are made is now important, it is fairly easy to topup with users, but a few thousand requests per minute now you can sustain even with free tier.